# Running an app on Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6, tomcat5.5

My Spring application runs on Tomcat 6.0 on localhost.

When I try to run it on 5.5, I get an error "Tomcat version 5.5 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4 Web modules".

How do I know the type of Web module my app is running on, and how do I make it run on 1.4?

Thanks.

EDIT:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>AppName</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.appname.connection.MySqlDBPooling</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct `J2EE` version (`<1.5`) of your dependencies for your development.

You also need define a compatible servlet version to use in  `web.xml`, i.e.

```
<web-app version="2.4" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Comment: on replacing the content, i'm getting an error: **cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'url-pattern'. No child element is expected at this point**

Comment: @James, naturally you also need to conform to the [specification](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd) of the servlet version 2.4 [which is the one supported by tomcat 5.5](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/index.html)

Comment: @James, good. It's the version of all your J2EE libraries. Normally these should be supplied by the app server and not be included when you compile your war-file.

Comment: I created a new Dynamic web project with module version 2.4, and then copied src and WebContent. That resolved my problem. I was able to run the app on Tomcat 5.5

Answer (score 1):

In project, `.settings` folder, find this file `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`, change the version of `facet="jst.web"` to 2.4 or 2.5 and `facet="jst.java"` to 1.4 like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <faceted-project>
      <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
      <fixed facet="jst.web"/>
      <fixed facet="java"/>
      <installed facet="java" version="1.4"/>
      <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.4"/>
      <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
    </faceted-project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same issue, i.e."cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'url-pattern'. No child element is expected at this point" , but after using advance version of JBOSS (jboss-as-7.1.1.Final), the issue was resolved.

if you face in Tomacat and getting same issue then try the advance version of it.